# Upload file to another domain

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've tried to upload an image using Laravel 5.1 from my current domain www.example.com to another domain like cdn.upload.com but still no luck to find a good way to do this. I've tried using:

```
$file->move('http://cdn.upload.com/public/images/', $filename);
```

but it return me error no "cannot create directory".

```
copy('cdn.upload.com', $filename);
```

but it not copy to the other domain.

Or is there any better way to make all image to a CDN? so i can access all the images across all domain?. i got about 3 domains need to access the images.

Thanks.

Comment: you could try curl or http post from a form, but you need to have a file on the destination server to handle, have they not got a API ? They prob have a php class for whatever method they use.

Comment: @David Hi, no they got no API. and its my own server. will see about curl. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the the [Filesystem/Cloud Storage](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem).

If you are using Amazon S3 or Rackspace the support is built in.

If not, it is [fairly simple to implement](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem#custom-filesystems).

The code is

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('file.txt', 'Contents');
```

Comment: Hi. I use Digital Ocean. is it supported?

Comment: Not out of the box, but I am certain it can. Filesystem uses https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Flysystem which supports a lot of providers.

Comment: Hi. One more thing. i have large project. Can you suggest me should I make separate application for it or not?

the project consist of 3 parts: for admin, for user and for super admin. THey all share same database, and images. 

is it good enough to make it separate project for user and admin? or should i make it on one project?

Comment: Personally if I am working with one database I keep it in the same project. Mostly because it is easier to reuse code.